# How to select custom dropdown list element with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a project where the native dropdowns are hidden and customized dropdowns are used. So, I cannot use the selenium select method (select and options are hidden and not usable). All dropdowns (salutation, country, bithdate, etc.) are implemented as customized dropdown.

```
<div class="medium-8 large-4 left column">
   <select name="register[personal][salutation]" id="register_personal_salutation" style="display: none;">
      <option value="mr">Herr</option>
      <option value="ms">Frau</option>
   </select>
   <div class="select-dropdown">
      <div class="selected">Herr</div>
      <div class="choices">
         <ul>
            <li>Herr</li>
            <li>Frau</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Solution 1 (not so nice): click on "select-dropdown" and click option. Its working, but not reusable.

Solution 2 (preferred): implement an own re-usable "customSelect" method so that I can select the correct option by given selector and option string (like webdriver select). But I dont know how to implement such a function. Has anybody already worked with custom dropdowns and has a solution or tips?

Comment: When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my solution. "optionClass" is the css selector of the options, "option" is the value which should be selected. I think its not the best solution, but one way to solve it. Any feedback, improvements or ideas?

```
public void customSelect(String optionClass, String option) {
            log.trace("I custom select the option " + option + " from the dropdown");
            int amountOptions = this.getNumOfElements(By.cssSelector(optionClass));
            for (int pos = 1; pos <= amountOptions; pos++) {
                String sortOption = this.getText(By.cssSelector(optionClass + ":nth-child(" + pos + ")"));
                if (sortOption.equalsIgnoreCase(option)) {
                    this.click(By.cssSelector(optionClass + ":nth-child(" + pos + ")"));
                    return;
                }
            }
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The dropdown does not contain the option " + option
                    + " and therefore it is not possible to select it.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following method worked just fine in case of a dropdown which has a default value also. 
Suppose you have as 'Not set' as a default value for most of your dropdowns, you can try this:

```
internal static void DropDownByValue(string defaultValue, string chosenValue)
    {
        DriverInstance.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
        var valueName =
            DriverInstance.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[contains (text (), '" + defaultValue + "')]"));
        var parent = valueName.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));
        SelectFromDropdown(parent, chosenValue);
    }

    public static void SelectFromDropdown(IWebElement button, string value)
    {
        var dropdown = new SelectElement(button);
        dropdown.SelectByText(value);
```

Hope this helps a bit.